# Is there a hidden exit at "The End"?

Tags: antichamber

After finishing the game, there is still a large square at "The End", is there more than one exit here?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the entire map there is one path to *The End* from *The Escape*, and that is the west entrance to *The End*. We also know that there is an exit from *The End* that leads to the actual end area. The simplest explanation is that the east exit from *The End* is that exit, and that the game does not register it when you do. Since there are no other exits from that room, I would infer that there are no other secret exits.

Answer (score 3):

by completing the game and starting it up again, [unless you have a version that doesn't save your progress] you can see from the map that the only thing connecting to "The End" is a dead end room, marked by a circle. this dead end is the final sequence of the game, involving the domes, the black cube and the antichamber logo